# CMake use Header generated by generate_product_version in other Source Files

Tags: c++, windows, cmake

I'm currently using the `generate_product_version` Function. This Function looks like this:

```
include (CMakeParseArguments)

set (GenerateProductVersionCurrentDir ${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR})

# generate_product_version() function
#
# This function uses VersionInfo.in template file and VersionResource.rc file
# to generate WIN32 resource with version information and general resource strings.
#
# Usage:
#   generate_product_version(
#     SomeOutputResourceVariable
#     NAME MyGreatProject
#     ICON ${PATH_TO_APP_ICON}
#     VERSION_MAJOR 2
#     VERSION_MINOR 3
#     VERSION_PATH ${BUILD_COUNTER}
#     VERSION_REVISION ${BUILD_REVISION}
#   )
# where BUILD_COUNTER and BUILD_REVISION could be values from your CI server.
#
# You can use generated resource for your executable targets:
#   add_executable(target-name ${target-files} ${SomeOutputResourceVariable})
#
# You can specify resource strings in arguments:
#   NAME               - name of executable (no defaults, ex: Microsoft Word)
#   BUNDLE             - bundle (${NAME} is default, ex: Microsoft Office)
#   ICON               - path to application icon (${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/product.ico by default)
#   VERSION_MAJOR      - 1 is default
#   VERSION_MINOR      - 0 is default
#   VERSION_PATCH      - 0 is default
#   VERSION_REVISION   - 0 is default
#   COMPANY_NAME       - your company name (no defaults)
#   COMPANY_COPYRIGHT  - ${COMPANY_NAME} (C) Copyright ${CURRENT_YEAR} is default
#   COMMENTS           - ${NAME} v${VERSION_MAJOR}.${VERSION_MINOR} is default
#   ORIGINAL_FILENAME  - ${NAME} is default
#   INTERNAL_NAME      - ${NAME} is default
#   FILE_DESCRIPTION   - ${NAME} is default
function(generate_product_version outfiles)
    set (options)
    set (oneValueArgs
        NAME
        BUNDLE
        ICON
        VERSION_MAJOR
        VERSION_MINOR
        VERSION_PATCH
        VERSION_REVISION
        COMPANY_NAME
        COMPANY_COPYRIGHT
        COMMENTS
        ORIGINAL_FILENAME
        INTERNAL_NAME
        FILE_DESCRIPTION)
    set (multiValueArgs)
    cmake_parse_arguments(PRODUCT "${options}" "${oneValueArgs}" "${multiValueArgs}" ${ARGN})

    if (NOT PRODUCT_BUNDLE OR "${PRODUCT_BUNDLE}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_BUNDLE "${PRODUCT_NAME}")
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_ICON OR "${PRODUCT_ICON}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_ICON "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/product.ico")
    endif()

    if (NOT PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR OR "${PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR 0)
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR OR "${PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR 0)
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_VERSION_PATCH OR "${PRODUCT_VERSION_PATCH}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_VERSION_PATCH 0)
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_VERSION_REVISION OR "${PRODUCT_VERSION_REVISION}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_VERSION_REVISION 0)
    endif()

    if (NOT PRODUCT_NAME OR "${PRODUCT_NAME}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_NAME "")
    endif()

    if (NOT PRODUCT_COMPANY_COPYRIGHT OR "${PRODUCT_COMPANY_COPYRIGHT}" STREQUAL "")
        string(TIMESTAMP PRODUCT_CURRENT_YEAR "%Y")
        set(PRODUCT_COMPANY_COPYRIGHT "${PRODUCT_COMPANY_NAME} (C) Copyright ${PRODUCT_CURRENT_YEAR}")
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_COMMENTS OR "${PRODUCT_COMMENTS}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_COMMENTS "${PRODUCT_NAME} v${PRODUCT_VERSION_MAJOR}.${PRODUCT_VERSION_MINOR}")
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_ORIGINAL_FILENAME OR "${PRODUCT_ORIGINAL_FILENAME}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_ORIGINAL_FILENAME "${PRODUCT_NAME}")
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_INTERNAL_NAME OR "${PRODUCT_INTERNAL_NAME}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_INTERNAL_NAME "${PRODUCT_NAME}")
    endif()
    if (NOT PRODUCT_FILE_DESCRIPTION OR "${PRODUCT_FILE_DESCRIPTION}" STREQUAL "")
        set(PRODUCT_FILE_DESCRIPTION "${PRODUCT_NAME}")
    endif()

    set (_VersionInfoFile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/VersionInfo_${PRODUCT_NAME}.h)
    set (_VersionResourceFile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/VersionResource_${PRODUCT_NAME}.rc)
    configure_file(
        ${GenerateProductVersionCurrentDir}/VersionInfo.in
        ${_VersionInfoFile}
        @ONLY)
    configure_file(
        ${GenerateProductVersionCurrentDir}/VersionResource.rc
        ${_VersionResourceFile}
        @ONLY)
    list(APPEND ${outfiles} ${_VersionInfoFile} ${_VersionResourceFile})
    set (${outfiles} ${${outfiles}} PARENT_SCOPE)
endfunction()
```

With this helper i set the Version Information for my created DLL on Windows.
As seen from the Function the Header is generated in the `{CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}`. If i now want to do something like this:

```
//src/test.cpp
#include "VersionInfo_Core.h" // Generated by the CMake Function

std::string version() {
    return std::string{PRODUCT_VERSION_FULL_STR};
}
```

What would be the best way to enable the usage of the generated headerfile?
One thing i thought about was adding the `CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR` to the include directory but i'm not sure if that would be kind of overkill.
Is it also possible to generate the files in the Source Directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the binary dir as an include directory. There's no other way to make headers for another directory available, and the source directory is no place for generated files.

If you want to avoid being able to include everything there, I would simply put that header in a dedicated directory:

```
set (_VersionInfoFile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include/VersionInfo_${PRODUCT_NAME}.h)
```

Then add `${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/include` as include directory.